# User "xxx" cannot create clusterrolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io at the cluster scope

Tags: kubernetes, rbac, prometheus

Below is the error messages I got:

`Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "prometheus-operator\\prometheus-operator-cluster-role-binding.yaml": User "xxx" cannot create clusterrolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io at the cluster scope.: "Required \"container.clusterRoleBindings.create\" permission." (post clusterrolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io)`

I was trying to deploy Prometheus to my gke (1.6.4) cluster.

Comment: What is the problem here? The message is pretty self-explanatory, your user "xxx" does not have permission to create cluster role bidings. You should ask your k8s cluster administrator to create this role binding for you or to add you to the admin role.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  I switched to as the owner of the gke project.  However, I still have problems to create the role bindings.   The following is the error msg:  `Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator-cluster-role.yaml": clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "prometheus-operator" is forbidden: attempt to grant extra privileges: [{[create] [extensions] ... `

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44350726/3777613

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46307325/gke-clusterrolebinding-for-cluster-admin-fails-with-permission-error