# Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating .. : clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io ...: attempt to grant extra privileges:

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus

Failed to create clusterroles. <> already assigned as the roles of "container engine admin" & "container engine cluster admin"

```
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "prometheus-
operator/prometheus-operator-cluster-role.yaml":
clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "prometheus-operator"
is forbidden: attempt to grant extra privileges: [{[create]
[extensions] [thirdpartyresources] [] []} {[*]
[monitoring.coreos.com] [alertmanagers] [] []} {[*]
[monitoring.coreos.com] [prometheuses] [] []} {[*]
[monitoring.coreos.com] [servicemonitors] [] []} {[*]
[apps] [statefulsets] [] []} {[*] [] [configmaps] [] []}
{[*] [] [secrets] [] []} {[list] [] [pods] [] []} {[delete]
[] [pods] [] []} {[get] [] [services] [] []} {[create]
[] [services] [] []} {[update] [] [services] [] []} {[get]
[] [endpoints] [] []} {[create] [] [endpoints] [] []}
{[update] [] [endpoints] [] []} {[list] [] [nodes]
[] []} {[watch] [] [nodes] [] []}]
user=&{<<my_account>>@gmail.com
[system:authenticated] map[]} ownerrules=[{[create]
[authorization.k8s.io] [selfsubjectaccessreviews]
[] []} {[get] [] [] [] [/api /api/* /apis /apis/*
/healthz /swaggerapi /swaggerapi/* /version]}]
ruleResolutionErrors=[]
```

Comment: I uses gke 1.6.4

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/role-based-access-control#setting_up_role-based_access_control

> Because of the way Container Engine checks permissions when you create a Role or ClusterRole, you must first create a RoleBinding that grants you all of the permissions included in the role you want to create.
>
> An example workaround is to create a RoleBinding that gives your Google identity a cluster-admin role before attempting to create additional Role or ClusterRolepermissions.
>
> This is a known issue in the Beta release of Role-Based Access Control in Kubernetes and Container Engine version 1.6.

So you need to bind your account to a cluster admin role.

Comment: Tks.  I have fixed this issue by following this article: https://coreos.com/operators/prometheus/docs/latest/troubleshooting.html

Comment: Inspite of the cluster admin role binding, i get same error.

Comment: I am also still getting the error with the binding. =\

Comment: but if you have the role `roles/owner` you are supposed to have every rights, so it should work without adding to yourself a `roles/container.clusterAdmin` or whatever, right ?

Comment: This no longer works on GKE, even if the service account is `roles/container.clusterAdmin` from IAM. I'm about to drop GKE.

Comment: If you are using a service account, the way to make this work is 

"gcloud iam service-accounts describe service-acc-name" followed by 

"kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding --clusterrole=cluster-admin --user=uniqueid"

where uniqueid you can get from the output of the first command. Sorry about the (non existent) formatting.

Answer (score 46):

I've got the same problem on Google Kubernetes Engine.

According to the answer of *enj* and the comment of *ccyang2005* please find the following snipet who solve my problem :)

## Step 1 : Get your identity

```
gcloud info | grep Account
```

Will output you something like `Account: [myname@example.org]`

## Step 2 : grant cluster-admin to your current identity

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding myname-cluster-admin-binding \
  --clusterrole=cluster-admin \
  --user=myname@example.org
```

Will output somthing like `Clusterrolebinding "myname-cluster-admin-binding" created`

---

After that, you'll be able to create CusterRoles

Comment: user nees to have permission Owner in IAM