# GKE clusterrolebinding for cluster-admin fails with permission error

Tags: permissions, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I've just created a new cluster using Google Container Engine running Kubernetes 1.7.5, with the new RBAC permissions enabled. I've run into a problem allocating permissions for some of my services which lead me to the following:

The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/role-based-access-control) for using container engine with RBAC state that the user must be granted the ability to create authorization roles by running the following command:

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding --clusterrole=cluster-admin [--user=<user-name>]
```

However, this fails due to lack of permissions (which I would assume are the very same permissions which we are attempting to grant by running the above command).

```
Error from server (Forbidden): 
User "<user-name>" cannot create clusterrolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io at the cluster scope.: 
  "Required \"container.clusterRoleBindings.create\" permission." 
  (post clusterrolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io)
```

Any help would be much appreciated as this is blocking me from creating the permissions needed by my cluster services.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Janos's answer will work for GKE clusters that have been created with a password, but I'd recommend avoiding using that password wherever possible (or creating your GKE clusters without a password).

Using IAM: To create that `ClusterRoleBinding`, the caller must have the `container.clusterRoleBindings.create` permission. Only the `OWNER` and `Kubernetes Engine Admin` IAM Roles contain that permission (because it allows modification of access control on your GKE clusters).

So, to allow `person@company.com` to run that command, they must be granted one of those roles. E.g.:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT \
  --member=user:person@company.com \
  --role=roles/container.admin
```

Comment: From my GCP experience, you not only need this permission (`container.clusterRoleBindings.create`) but also this one `container.clusterRoles.bind`. With this you can create your own custom role and don't need to use the big `Kubernetes Engine Admin` predefined role. Documentation is here : https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/api-permissions

Comment: GCP / GKE: i also needed to add a ClusterRoleBinding inside gke to my user as well to get it working.

Answer (score 33):

If your kubeconfig was created automatically by `gcloud` then your user is not the all powerful admin user - which you are trying to create a binding for.

Use [`gcloud container clusters describe <clustername> --zone <zone>`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/describe) on the cluster and look for the `password` field.

Thereafter execute `kubectl --username=admin --password=FROMABOVE create clusterrolebinding ...`

Comment: I also had to update kubectl to the newest version, before (v1.6) even with this solution I was still getting the same error message. Maybe this helps someone else too.

Comment: I get `Error: unknown flag: --username`