# Accessing Kubernetes API in GKE using service accounts

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have my Kubernetes cluster running in GKE I want to run an application outside the cluster and talk to the Kubernetes API.

By using password retrieved from running:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials cluster-2 --log-http
```

I am able to access the API with Basic authentication.
But I want to create multiple Kubernetes service accounts and configure them with required authorization and use appropriately.

So, I created service accounts and obtained the tokens using:

```
kubectl create serviceaccount sauser1
kubectl get serviceaccounts sauser1 -o yaml
kubectl get secret sauser1-token-<random-string-as-retrieved-from-previous-command> -o yaml
```

If I try to access the Kubernetes API with the obtained token using Bearer authentication then I get a 401 HTTP error. I thought that some permissions may have to be set for the service account, so based on the documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/rbac/), I created below YAML file:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: pod-reader
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: pod-reader
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: sauser1
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: pod-reader
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

and tried to apply it using the below command:

```
kubectl apply -f default-sa-rolebinding.yaml
```

I got the following error:

```
clusterrolebinding "pod-reader" created
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "default-sa-rolebinding.yaml"
: clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "pod-reader" is forbidden: attempt to g
rant extra privileges: [PolicyRule{Resources:["pods"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["g
et"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["pods"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule
{Resources:["pods"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["list"]}] user=&{xyz@gmail.
com  [system:authenticated] map[authenticator:[GKE]]} ownerrules=[PolicyRule{Res
ources:["selfsubjectaccessreviews"], APIGroups:["authorization.k8s.io"], Verbs:[
"create"]} PolicyRule{NonResourceURLs:["/api" "/api/*" "/apis" "/apis/*" "/healt
hz" "/swagger-2.0.0.pb-v1" "/swagger.json" "/swaggerapi" "/swaggerapi/*" "/versi
on"], Verbs:["get"]}] ruleResolutionErrors=[]
```

I dont know how to proceed from here. Is my approach correct or am I missing something here?

**UPDATE**: As per the post referred by @JanosLenart in the comments, modified the kubectl command and the above error is not observed. But accessing the API, still gives 401 error. The curl command that I am using is:

```
curl -k -1 -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" https://<ip-address>/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods -v
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GKE clusterrolebinding for cluster-admin fails with permission error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46307325/gke-clusterrolebinding-for-cluster-admin-fails-with-permission-error). Your approach is sound otherwise!

Comment: @JanosLenart The other post, resolved the forbidden error that I got when creating clusterrole. But accessing the API, still gives 401 error. The curl command that I am using is: `curl -k -1 -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" https://<ip-address>/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods -v`

Answer (score 5):

@Janos pointed out the potential problem, however I think you will need an actual Cloud IAM Service Account as well, because you said:

> I want to run an application outside the cluster [...]

If you're authenticating to GKE from outside, I believe you can only use the Google IAM identities. (I might be wrong, if so, please let me know.)

In this case, what you need to do:

1. Create an IAM service account and download a json key file of it.
2. set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to that file.
3. either:

   - use RBAC like in your question to give permissions to the email address of the IAM Service Account
   - use IAM Roles to give the IAM Service Account on the GKE API (e.g. `Container Developer` role is usually sufficient)
4. Use `kubectl` command against the cluster (make sure you have a `.kube/config` file  with the cluster's IP/CA cert beforehand) with the environment variable above, it should work.

Comment: I will try this out. But shouldn't the Kubernetes service account approach work without having to create Google IAM service account? I am accessing the Kubernetes API directly and not through the GKE listed APIs

Comment: This is a better answer than the other +1

Answer (score 0):

YMMV

I managed to get it work without USING an actual Cloud IAM Service Account

First, I decided to use an shell inside GKE's k8s cluster by running

```
kubectl run curl-random --image=radial/busyboxplus:curl -i --tty --rm
```

Second, I made sure I decoded my token by copying the token and then running through

```
pbpaste | base64 -D
```

Third, I created the rolebinding for the serviceaccount, NOT the username.

`kubectl create clusterrolebinding shaoserverless-cluster-admin-binding --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=default:shaoserverless`

The third step was particularly tricky but I got the inspiration since the error message used to be

`Unknown user \"system:serviceaccount:default:shaoserverless\"",`

Lastly, then this works

`curl -k -1 -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" https://<ip-address>/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods -v`