# cannot query kubernetes (unauthorized): endpoints is forbidden: User cannot list endpoints in the namespace

Tags: erlang, kubernetes, elixir, google-kubernetes-engine

I am running `kubernetes 1.9.4` on my `gke` cluster

I have two pods , `gate` which is trying to connect to `coolapp`, both written in `elixir`

I am using [libcluster](https://github.com/bitwalker/libcluster/issues/54) to connect my nodes
I get the following error:

`[libcluster:app_name] cannot query kubernetes (unauthorized): endpoints is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:staging:default" cannot list endpoints in the namespace "staging": Unknown user "system:serviceaccount:staging:default"`

here is my config in **gate** under `config/prod`:

```
 config :libcluster,
 topologies: [
   app_name: [
     strategy: Cluster.Strategy.Kubernetes,
     config: [
       kubernetes_selector: "tier=backend",
       kubernetes_node_basename: System.get_env("MY_POD_NAMESPACE") || "${MY_POD_NAMESPACE}"]]]
```

here is my configuration:

**vm-args**

```
## Name of the node
-name ${MY_POD_NAMESPACE}@${MY_POD_IP}
## Cookie for distributed erlang
-setcookie ${ERLANG_COOKIE}
# Enable SMP automatically based on availability
-smp auto
```

**creating the secrets:**

```
kubectl create secret generic erlang-config --namespace staging --from-literal=erlang-cookie=xxxxxx
kubectl create configmap vm-config --namespace staging --from-file=vm.args
```

**gate/deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: gate
  namespace: staging
spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 1
  strategy:
      type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: gate
        tier: backend
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 0
        runAsNonRoot: false
      containers:
      - name: gate
        image: gcr.io/development/gate:0.1.7
        args:
          - foreground
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config-volume
          mountPath: /beamconfig
        env:
        - name: MY_POD_NAMESPACE
          value: staging
        - name: MY_POD_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.podIP
        - name: MY_POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: RELEASE_CONFIG_DIR
          value: /beamconfig
        - name: ERLANG_COOKIE
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: erlang-config
              key: erlang-cookie
      volumes:
      - name: config-volume
        configMap:
          name: vm-config
```

**coolapp/deployment.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: coolapp
  namespace: staging
spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 1
  strategy:
      type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: coolapp
        tier: backend
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 0
        runAsNonRoot: false
     # volumes
      volumes:
      - name: config-volume
        configMap:
          name: vm-config
      containers:
      - name: coolapp
        image: gcr.io/development/coolapp:1.0.3
        volumeMounts:
        - name: secrets-volume
          mountPath: /secrets
          readOnly: true
        - name: config-volume
          mountPath: /beamconfig
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        args:
          - "foreground"
        env:
        - name: MY_POD_NAMESPACE
          value: staging
        - name: MY_POD_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.podIP
        - name: MY_POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: REPLACE_OS_VARS
          value: "true"
        - name: RELEASE_CONFIG_DIR
          value: /beamconfig
        - name: ERLANG_COOKIE
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: erlang-config
              key: erlang-cookie
        # proxy_container
      - name: cloudsql-proxy
        image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.11
        command: ["/cloud_sql_proxy", "--dir=/cloudsql",
            "-instances=staging:us-central1:com-staging=tcp:5432",
            "-credential_file=/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json"]
        volumeMounts:
          - name: cloudsql-instance-credentials
            mountPath: /secrets/cloudsql
            readOnly: true
          - name: cloudsql
            mountPath: /cloudsql
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The default [service account](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/) for the `staging` namespace (in which apparently your Pods using libcluster are running) lacks [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/rbac/) permissions to *get endpoints* in that namespace.**

Likely your application requires a number of other permissions (that are not mentioned in the above error message) to work correctly; identifying all such permissions is out of scope for SO.

A way to resolve this issue is to grant **superuser permissions** that service account. This is not a secure solution but a stop gap fix.

```
$ kubectl create clusterrolebinding make-staging-sa-cluster-admin \
    --serviceaccount=staging:default \
    --clusterrole=cluster-admin

clusterrolebinding "make-staging-sa-cluster-admin" created
```

To grant the **specific permission only** (get endpoints in the staging namespace) you would need to create a [Role](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole) first:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: some-permissions
  namespace: staging
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["endpoints"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
```

And create a [RoleBinding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/rbac/#rolebinding-and-clusterrolebinding) for the default service account in the staging namespace:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: give-default-sa-some-permissions
  namespace: staging
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
  namespace: staging
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: some-permissions
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Comment: I get `Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "some-permissions.yaml": roles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "some-permissions" is forbidden: attempt to grant extra privileges:`

Comment: You did not specify your environment, but if you are working with GKE then check https://stackoverflow.com/a/46316672/371954 . Otherwise, I suggest you start a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Not an erlang/elixir or libcluster user, but  it seems it is trying to use the default service account for the namespace to try and query the master for a list of endpoints available in the cluster.

The readme for libcluster says as much:

> If set to Cluster.Strategy.Kubernetes, it will use the Kubernetes API
>   to query endpoints based on a basename and label selector, using the
>   token and namespace injected into every pod; once it has a list of
>   endpoints, it uses that list to form a cluster, and keep it up to
>   date.

Reading the [code for the kubernetes.ex in libcluster](https://github.com/bitwalker/libcluster/blob/master/lib/strategy/kubernetes.ex#L66-L67) and the error you get confirm as much.

You will need to setup a ClusterRole and RoleBinding for the service account in the staging namespace. This will allow libcluster to dynamically query the master to discover other erlang nodes in the cluster/namespace.

Here are some handy resources for follow up reading:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/service-accounts-admin/
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/rbac/
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/