# GKE traefik fails to create rbac permissions

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, traefik, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to install `traefik` as an ingress controller on `GKE` (google cloud kubernetes engine) and when I try:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/containous/traefik/master/examples/k8s/traefik-rbac.yaml
```

I have this error:

> Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating
>   "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/containous/traefik/master/examples/k8s/traefik-rbac.yaml":
>   clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "traefik-ingress-controller" is
>   forbidden: attempt to grant extra privileges:
>   [PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], Resources:["services"], Verbs:["get"]}
>   PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], Resources:["services"], Verbs:["list"]}
>   PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], Resources:["services"], Verbs:["watch"]}
>   PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], Resources:["endpoints"], Verbs:["get"]}
>   PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], Resources:["endpoints"], Verbs:["list"]}
>   PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], Resources:["endpoints"], Verbs:["watch"]}
>   PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], Resources:["secrets"], Verbs:["get"]}
>   PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], Resources:["secrets"], Verbs:["list"]}
>   PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], Resources:["secrets"], Verbs:["watch"]}
>   PolicyRule{APIGroups:["extensions"], Resources:["ingresses"],
>   Verbs:["get"]} PolicyRule{APIGroups:["extensions"],
>   Resources:["ingresses"], Verbs:["list"]}
>   PolicyRule{APIGroups:["extensions"], Resources:["ingresses"],
>   Verbs:["watch"]}] user=&{IzoPi4a@gmail.com  [system:authenticated]
>   map[user-assertion.cloud.google.com:[ADKE0IBz9kwSuZRZkfbLil8iC/ijcmJJmuys2DvDGxoxQ5yP6Pdq1IQs3JRwDmd/lWm2vGdMXGB4h1QKiwx+3uV2ciTb/oQNtkthBvONnVp4fJGOSW1S+8O8dqvoUNRLNeB5gADNn1TKEYoB+JvRkjrkTOxtIh7rPugLaP5Hp7thWft9xwZqF9U4fgYHnPjCdRgvMrDvGIK8z7ONljYuStpWdJDu7LrPpT0L]]}
>   ownerrules=[PolicyRule{APIGroups:["authorization.k8s.io"],
>   Resources:["selfsubjectaccessreviews" "selfsubjectrulesreviews"],
>   Verbs:["create"]} PolicyRule{NonResourceURLs:["/api" "/api/*" "/apis"
>   "/apis/*" "/healthz" "/openapi" "/openapi/*" "/swagger-2.0.0.pb-v1"
>   "/swagger.json" "/swaggerapi" "/swaggerapi/*" "/version" "/version/"],
>   Verbs:["get"]}] ruleResolutionErrors=[]

The problem is this part only, the other one is created successfully:

```
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-controller
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - services
      - endpoints
      - secrets
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - extensions
    resources:
      - ingresses
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
```

Based on docs ( https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/role-based-access-control) I tried executing this command but I still get the same error

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding --clusterrole=cluster-admin --user=MY_EMAIL_THAT_I_LOGIN_INTO_GCP
```

Has anyone ever manage to fix this? or it just does not work ?

I am trying to make a kubernetes cluster without loadBalancer in order to be cheap on my local machine (minikube), I have no such problems.

Comment: It sounds a problem related to your user. Not enough permissions to handle clusterrolebindings resources..

Comment: i am the only user. Its my personal account. Perhaps i need to "enable" something to my user ? but i have no idea what

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46307325/gke-clusterrolebinding-for-cluster-admin-fails-with-permission-error

Comment: omg this seems to be doing the trick... man that is really complicated. I will need ~  1 hour to finish my tests and close this question ( somehow ? )

Comment: @NicolaBen can you post answer so i can accept it as an answer to the thread

Comment: Don't worry, you'll have other occasions to upvote ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So for everyone who is trying to install traefik on GKE, and you get stuck with that error message, just do that first https://stackoverflow.com/a/46316672/1747159

```sh
# Get password value
$ gcloud container clusters describe CUSTER_NAME --zone ZONE_NAME | grep password

# Pass username and password parameters
$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/containous/traefik/master/examples/k8s/traefik-rbac.yaml --username=admin --password=PASSWORD
```

Thanks Nicola Ben for helping me figure it out

Answer (score 2):

The main problem here is that your current user has not enough rights to do this.
To create the necessary binding:

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding \                                               
    --clusterrole=cluster-admin \
    --user=$(gcloud config get-value core/account)
```

Thanks to [istio](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/platform-setup/gke/) for the idea.