# Cannot create clusterrolebinding on fresh GKE cluster

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I provisioned a managed GKE cluster (Kubernetes version 1.9.4-gke.1) with basic authentication *disabled*. When i try to create RBAC configuration (for running my ingress controller) I get a following error:
`Error from server (Forbidden): clusterrolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io is forbidden: User "XXX@gmail.com" cannot create clusterrolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io at the cluster scope: Required "container.clusterRoleBindings.create" permission.`

I found two related questions:

1. [GKE clusterrolebinding for cluster-admin fails with permission error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46307325/gke-clusterrolebinding-for-cluster-admin-fails-with-permission-error)
2. [User "xxx" cannot create clusterrolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io at the cluster scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44345678/user-xxx-cannot-create-clusterrolebindings-rbac-authorization-k8s-io-at-the-cl)

First one contains a solution when basic authentication is enabled for the cluster which is not my case. And second question does not have an answer.

My user is not owner of the GCP project but it has `editor` role in the project. I found that this behavior was observed by [others](http://kubeless.io/docs/GKE-deployment/).

Please, advise how can I add the missing permission or otherwise defined RBAC on the GKE cluster when the cluster has basic authentication disabled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To create that `ClusterRoleBinding`, the caller must have `container.clusterRoleBindings.create` permission through GCP IAM. Only the `OWNER` and `Kubernetes Admin` IAM Roles contain that permission (because it allows modification of access control on your GKE clusters).

So, to allow `person@company.com` to run that command, they must be granted one of those roles. I'd recommend the `Kubernetes Admin` role.:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT --member=user:person@company.com --role=roles/container.admin
```